# NX how to use development build for libs when serving angular app

Tags: angular, npm, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I have a NX workspace with an angular app

I have some libs that this app uses
ie: **data-access** and **state**

The problem is that when I serve my angular app the production version of the libs are being used, even if I build the libs in development mode.

examples:

`nx serve my-app --configuration development`

this does build the app in dev but the referenced libs are using production builds.

so i tried building the libs in dev just before running serve and the prod version is still used

```
nx build data-access --configuration development
nx build state --configuration development
nx serve my-app --configuration development
```

I feel like I am missing something really obvious here.

Can someone help me figure out how to serve the app using the dev builds of my libraries

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:  nx build data-access --configuration=development

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).